# Inserting at the end of queue in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, queue

I am trying to insert node at the end of queue and facing below error . This is simple fundamental error while compiling the code but making my life hard.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct UNIX  {

char str[20];

struct UNIX *next;
}examp;

examp *head=NULL;

int insert_last(char *s)

{
    examp *new,*slide;
    slide=head;
    new = (examp *)malloc(sizeof(examp));

      if(!new)
           return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while(slide->next!=NULL)
        slide=slide->next;
    slide->next=new;
    new->str=s;
    new->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {   head=new;
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
void display (void);
int main()

{


insert_last("hello ");
insert_last("how ");
insert_last("have ");
insert_last("you ");
insert_last("been ");
insert_last("! ");
display();

}

void display(void)
{
    examp *slide;
    slide=head;
    while(slide->next!=NULL)
    { printf("%s   ",slide->str);
       slide=slide->next;
    }

}
```

Error :stack_queue.c:27:10: error: assignment to expression with array type
  new->str=s;

Update : Using strncpy reolved the error , but code is not working as expected and stopping unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to a static array like that. Consider using `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy the contents of the character string instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a string to an array! An array have its own memory, you can write or read elements in the array, but cannot assign an address.

You can eventually copy the string `s` contents to the array:

```
strncpy(new->str, s, 19);
new->str[19] = '\0';    //Close the string in case of overflow.
```

We used `strncpy` to limit the copied characters to the array size (19 chars + the ending `'\0'`).

Comment: however output is not coming as expected.

Comment: @theartist33 What is not as expected? The string content is correct? See my update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. Only replace in `new->str=s;` to `strcpy(new->str, s);` (ie. `s` will be copy in to `new->str`)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct UNIX  {

char str[20];

struct UNIX *next;
}examp;

examp *head=NULL;

int insert_last(char *s)

{
    examp *new,*slide;
    slide=head;
    new = (examp *)malloc(sizeof(examp));

      if(!new)
           return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while(slide->next!=NULL)
        slide=slide->next;
    slide->next=new;
    strcpy(new->str, s);
    new->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {   head=new;
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
void display (void);
int main()

{


insert_last("hello ");
insert_last("how ");
insert_last("have ");
insert_last("you ");
insert_last("been ");
insert_last("! ");
display();

}

void display(void)
{
    examp *slide;
    slide=head;
    while(slide->next!=NULL)
    { printf("%s   ",slide->str);
       slide=slide->next;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated you will have to use strcpy (or strncpy) in order to assign the string.

Asides from that I wanted to mention two things:

1. Do not forget to free your memory allocated by malloc. Create a method to free a single node (examp) then you can also provide a method to destroy the whole list.
2. I would suggest to rename the variable new to avoid confusion (pure C compiler may deal with it, but C/C++ compiler will most likely get into trouble).

Considering your update:
Take a look at the following line

```
while(slide->next!=NULL)
```

At this time slide does not even exist (it is NULL), still you perform an operation on the pointer. This is the reason why the program crashes.

Comment: I am now freeing up memory by free(node) and also changed 'new' to 'node' , still not a solution

Comment: You are trying to access an element on a null pointer. Thats the reason for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the first call `insert_last("hello ")`:

```
int insert_last(char *s)
{
examp *new,*slide;
slide=head;
new = (examp *)malloc(sizeof(examp));

  if(!new)
       return(EXIT_FAILURE);
while(slide->next!=NULL)
    slide=slide->next;
```

when you call it first time, head is NULL, so slide becomes NULL, but you don't check it, and call it in

```
while(slide->next!=NULL)
```

Here slide is null for the frst function call